# How to relate two different dataframes to make calculations

Tags: r, database, relational-database

I know how to work and computing math/statistics with one dataframe. But, what happens when I have to deal with two? For example:

```
> df1
   supervisor salesperson
1 Supervisor1        Matt
2 Supervisor2      Amelia
3 Supervisor2     Philip

> df2
  month   channel Matt Amelia Philip
1   Jan  Internet   10     50     20
2   Jan Cellphone   20     60     30
3   Feb  Internet   40     40     30
4   Feb Cellphone   30    120     40
```

How can I compute the sales by supervisor grouped by channel in a efficient and generalizable way?. Is there any methodology or criteria when you need to relate two or more dataframes in order to compute the data you need?

PS: The number are the sales made by each sales person.

Comment: Note, you have typos, i.e. `Philip` and `Phillip` and you also have `supervisor2` twice

Comment: @Sotos I corrected the Philip mistake, thanks!. However, supervisor2 is not a mistake: Amelia and Philip have the same supervisor.

Comment: @Chris: I think first you have to transpose the data for "channel" and ake two different column, parallelly you have to add a field called "salesperson" in DF2. Then your DF2 will look like: month, ch_internet, ch_cellphone,salesperson. and also your record will be reduced. Then you join both of the DF easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea of converting to long and merging using `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
 gather(salesperson, val, -c(1:2)) %>% 
 left_join(., df1, by = 'salesperson') %>% 
 spread(salesperson, val, fill = 0) %>% 
 group_by(channel, supervisor) %>% 
 summarise_at(vars(names(.)[4:6]), funs(sum))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 5
> # Groups:   channel [?]
>   channel   supervisor  Amelia  Matt Philip
>   <fct>     <fct>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
> 1 Cellphone Supervisor1     0.   50.     0.
> 2 Cellphone Supervisor2   180.    0.    70.
> 3 Internet  Supervisor1     0.   50.     0.
> 4 Internet  Supervisor2    90.    0.    50.
> ```

**NOTE:** You can also add `month` in the `group_by`